# Remove 'FocusRing' of a focused View

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I am working with focus on a MacOS (13.0) app and I would like to remove the blue halo, called `FocusRing`.
I've seen people asking about it on TextField but I am working with focus on Views using `.focusable()` on those Views (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePrpK.png for image example).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            RectangleView(width: 100, height: 200, color: .yellow)
                .focusable()
                .offset(x: 100, y: 150)
        
            RectangleView(width: 100, height: 200, color: .purple)
                .focusable()
                .offset(x: 300, y: 60)
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove it with a View extension or something else ?

Comment: It seems the `FocusRing` has gone away on macos 13 Ventura, I do not get any focus rings. Using Xcode 14.1-beta2.

Comment: Ok good to know but as I said, I am doing my app for MacOS 12.3 BigSur and not 13 Ventura :/ @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I am now on Ventura and the ring is still here

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue using the code you show. I do not get any focus rings at all, using Xcode 14.1 and target macos 13.0. Tested on real iMac, not using `Previews/Canvas`.

Comment: Just tested it, and it's still here @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: Sorry mate, I just do not get the rings. I am now on iMac (intel) with Ventura 13.1. It would be good if someone else could try this code and report back their findings.